# How to close a child panel properly to detect its parent panel in wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a page in wicket,and i have a list view.from list view i am opening a panel.
now this part works fine.i can able to close it properly and can able to detect the page components.Now in the Panel (Parent panel) i have a button ,using that i am opening another panel(child panel).after closing the child panel,it shows unable to detect components from the parent panel.i want to know how we can get the parent panel components opened previously?

```
this.showPanel = new MyAjaxButton("show_status_button", new Model<>(getString("label.show_status_button")));

    this.showPanel.setCommand(new AbstractButtonCommand<Serializable>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4885881327074792340L;

        @Override
        public void submit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            DataProvider dp = new DataProvider();
            MyBean id = dp.getId(bean);
            String contentId=modalWindow.getContentId();


            modalWindow.setContent(new ShowPanel(id));
            modalWindow.setInitialWidth(NEW_STATUS_PANEL_WIDTH);
            modalWindow.setInitialHeight(NEW_STATUS_PANEL_HEIGHT);
            modalWindow.setCloseButtonCallback(callback)

            modalWindow.setWindowClosedCallback(new WindowClosedCallback() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    target.add(container);  //this panel's container
                }
            });
        modalWindow.show(target);

        }
```

the error which i am getting:

```
org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ComponentNotFoundException: Could not find component 'form:panel:content:container:show_status_button' on page 'class ps.web.MyPage.pages.DisPage
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageAndComponentProvider.getComponent(PageAndComponentProvider.java:181)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.getComponent(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:239)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:784)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact error into your question. Don't forget to show the line that causes the error - we can't see line numbers in stack overflow.

Comment: Don't forget to show the line that causes the error - **we can't see line numbers in stack overflow.**

Comment: It seems your `showPanel` component is either not added to a parent container or it is removed from it later.